# why "git fetch origin bugfix" does not work?

Tags: git

I tried this to fetch a remote branch:

```
% git fetch origin bugfix
```

And the console tells me:

```
From github.com:*****/sdn-prjkt
 * branch            bugfix     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Looks like it's fetched. But when I try to list all branches but it's not fetched to local:

```
% git branch
* main
```

Still in remote:

```
% git branch -a
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/bugfix
  remotes/origin/main
```

May I know why?

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_configured_remote_tracking_branches.

Comment: check out the branch and track with a local branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your branches are *yours*.  The `git fetch` command obtains *commits:* you and they<sup>1</sup> *share* the commits, which are all always, completely read-only, so they can't change yours and you can't change theirs and therefore it's completely safe to share them.  But `git fetch` does not get any *branches*.

Instead, your Git remembers *their branches* using your *remote-tracking names*.  You can list these with `git branch -r`, or with `git branch -a` as you just did.  The remote-tracking names for the remote named `origin` are spelled with `origin/` in front of them: `origin/main`, `origin/bugfix`, and so on.

For no good reason, `git branch -r` shows these as `origin/bugfix` but `git branch -a` shows them as `remotes/origin/bugfix`.  The fact is that each of these names is shortened:

- your branch name `main` is short for `refs/heads/main`;
- your remote-tracking name `origin/main` is short for `refs/remotes/origin/main`;

and so on.  Git drops `refs/heads/` from branch names when shortening them, drops `refs/tags/` from tag names when shortening tag names, and drops `refs/remotes/`, or sometimes just `refs/`, from remote-tracking names when shortening those.

If you would like to have *your own branch name*, you simply tell Git: *Create, for me, a new branch name `bugfix`, using the same commit I just saw on their Git that they call `bugfix`, which I call `origin/bugfix`.*

The *long* form of this command is:

```
git branch --track bugfix origin/bugfix
```

after which `git checkout bugfix` or `git switch bugfix` finds that you have a branch named `bugfix`, and switches to that branch and extracts that branch's *tip commit* as the current commit.  (Remember, each commit holds a full snapshot of every file—though in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form—so for you to *use* a commit, Git has to *extract its files*.)

There's a shortcut, though:

```
git checkout bugfix
```

or:

```
git switch bugfix
```

starts out ready to complain that, hey, there's no branch named `bugfix`, we can't possibly do that—but then, because you didn't say `--no-guess`, they use what Git used to call *DWIM mode* to *guess* whether they should *create* a branch named `bugfix`.

To guess, they look at all your remote-tracking names, as if you'd run `git branch -r`.  If there's exactly one that looks right—such as `origin/bugfix`—they'll automatically do that `git branch` command for you.<sup>2</sup>  Then, now that you have a `bugfix`, they can switch to it successfully.  You'll get a message about having switched to a newly created branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>*You* here means *your Git software, running on your computer, operating on your repository*.  *They* means *their Git software, running on their computer, operating on their repository*.  Note that there are two independent Git repositories here.  The `git fetch` operation means *Call up their Git and get any commits they have, that I don't, that they are willing to hand over.  Then, based on what you saw for their branch names, create or update my remote-tracking names to match their branch names.*

<sup>2</sup>Whether they use `git branch --track` or `git branch --no-track` is actually configurable, but the default is to use `--track`.  Be careful with this verb *track:* Git overuses it a lot, so when you see it elsewhere in Git, it *might* refer to this, but it might refer to something else.